# Autoadjusting Text in a Tab Layout

Tags: android, xml, tabs

I created a custom tab layout with awesome fonts library.

The Custom Tab layout is as follows

`<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#888888"/>`

The main tablyout design is as follows

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#D71A21"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
            app:tabTextColor="#888888"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#000000"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="#888888"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I ran the program in my tab I got an output like this

[image]

As you can the scroll able bar is all aligned perfectly, but when I installed the app in another device I got an output like this

[image]

What is actually going wrong here?

Should I use some inbuilt library that allows the text to scale automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried some blogs and tutorials and came to know about "Scroll able tab layout". Even though this allows the icon and text to align perfectly.

Just add this in tab layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      ...........
      app:tabMode="scrollable
      ........... />
```

I also request the future visitors to update the answer in case something better comes in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

well its because of the layout is set to `wrap_content` and on smaller screens it wraps the content like that, just try giving it a proper height of `40 or 60dp` whatever u like and see,  I think it will solve your issue

try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#D71A21"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
        app:tabTextColor="#888888"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#000000"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Comment: I tried but it is still the same. Do you have any other solution??

Comment: well u can also try to reduce the size of the text? something like this `android:textSize="20sp"` ,

Comment: For now I did this `app:tabMode="scrollable"` which made the text to align perfectly in a small screen also allowed me to scroll to reach the tab I needed